# Python: Lock a directory

Tags: python, linux, locking, filelock

I have a python script which gets executed via cron every 5 minutes.

This script operates on a directory.

Sometimes it takes longer then 5 minutes and I want to avoid that two jobs run in parallel.

I tried to use the library [flockcontext](https://github.com/AntoineCezar/flockcontext) but this can only lock files.

I get this exception:

```
   with flockcontext.FlockOpen(directory, 'r'):
  File "/.../flockcontext/flock_open.py", line 54, in __enter__
    self.fd = open(self._filepath, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'my-dir'
```

How to lock a directory with a context manager?

I know that I could work-around this issue by locking a file (maybe var/lock/foo), but I would like to have a solution (not a work-around).

PS: I know that this lock only prevents other processes to operate on this directory who check this lock before starting.

Comment: @FlyingTeller this is not a duplicate, since the other question locks a file, not a directory.

Comment: A better duplicate candidate would be [How can I lock a directory in C on a linux machine](//stackoverflow.com/q/8816941); the Python `os.open()` function and `fcntl` module are essentially the low-level C library functions, the answers in that post apply equally to Python.